# What is the best data type for DATE and TIME

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have an application that saves the date and time of a transaction. My initial database design is to create separate fields for `DATE` as date and `TIME` as varchar. My second option is to have a single field with `DATETIME`.

**What is the difference of these two??**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Datetime vs Date and Time Mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356268/datetime-vs-date-and-time-mysql)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend to use TIMESTAMP as this will help you to track every change made to your database. You shou;d use DateTime datatype if you want to store specific value of date and time in your column. But if you want to track the changes made in your values then I would recommend to use TIMESTAMP. From the MYSQL [Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html):

> The DATETIME type is used when you need values that contain both date and time information. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.
>
> ...
>
> The TIMESTAMP data type has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-09 03:14:07' UTC. It has varying properties, depending on the MySQL version and the SQL mode the server is running in.

Comment: what would happen after 2038??

Comment: @user2419435:- My best guess is by that time either some new data type with more range will come but as of now no official news! A good read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Answer (score 2):

Use timestamp.  I would advise against storing date and time separately.  The reason is that when you want to use them in a where clause you can find yourself adding them together.

Answer (score 0):

datetime will give the date and the time on which the transcation was made like 
12-10-2012 12:00:00
So, instead of using two seperate field we can use one ie datetime

Comment: so the best is to use datetime