# mysql queries too slow on new data set - mariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, mysql-workbench, mariadb

I need help regarding our reporting project that we are developing.
The system builds queries on user demand.

The development data that we were working on initially was with largest table of around 8 millions rows. The queries are highly optimised and are working fine on this DB with this amount of data.

Now, we have new data set half the size of the first one and most of the queries that we run are too slow..

Simple comparation: if a query took less than a 1s on the first data set, on the new data set it takes around 30s.

Difference: the only difference is that in the new dataset we also add DATETIME values. Previously we were working only with DATEs.

So, Is there some extra processing done in mysql engine regarding the DATETIME type and should I set something differently? Maybe some config flag? Some good practice in order to speed up the processing?

Any thoughts are welcomed.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you evaluating on the datetime?

Comment: @TGray it might. The user selects the columns in the system and yes, it might be evaluated on the datetime. I mentioned that as a possible reason.

Comment: Check out this post:  one of the answers may show fruit for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356268/datetime-vs-date-and-time-mysql

Comment: There is nothing substantively different between `DATE` and `DATETIME`.  Something else must be different.  Please `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, and show us the `SELECT`.  Are the machines using the same kind of disk?  And same amount of RAM?  And same `my.cnf` settings?

Answer (score 0):

So, to sum up an answer to this as I found a solution:

There was a particular problem with specific join which increased the load exponentially and resulted in extreme degradation of the performance.
The DATETIME column might affect a small decrease of the performance, but not significantly high (talking this on the info provided in [Datetime vs Date and Time Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356268/datetime-vs-date-and-time-mysql) by @T Gray). I even didn't make comparison since in my case it didn't show any specific decrease.

Thanks for your answers folks!